# Jquery: Insert HTML before element

Tags: jquery

So I have the following:

```
  <li class="   last-item SunItem-8"><a href="#><span>Blah</span></a></li>
```

But I need to have Jquery insert a few HTML elements before this, so it looks like:

```
  </li></ul><li><ul>
```

so it will look like this:

```
   </li></ul><li><ul><li class="   last-item SunItem-8"><a href="#><span>Blah</span></a></li>
```

Any help is appreciated

Here is more context - I bound by a menu embed in a CMS (dont have source code), so this is what the menu looks like

```
 <li class="dir dgn-root    Item-2">
   <a href="#" title=""><span>Menu1</span></a><div class="mega_submenu Column2 Column3" style="display: none;">
 <ul class="mega_submenu_ul">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li class="   first-item SunItem-1">
         <a href="#" title="Templates">
            <span>Templates</span>
         </a>
        </li>
       <li class="   SunItem-2">
          <a href="#" title="Questions and Answers">
            <span>Questions and Answers</span>
          </a>
       </li>
       <li class="   SunItem-3">
             <a href="#" title="Template Package">
               <span>Template Package</span>
             </a>
       </li>
        <li class="   SunItem-4">
             <a href="#" title="Silver Package">
              <span>Silver Package</span>
             </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <ul>
       <li class="   SunItem-5">
             <a href="#" title="Gold Package">
                <span>Gold Package</span>
             </a>
       </li>
       <li class="   SunItem-6">
             <a href="#" title="Platinum Package">
                 <span>Platinum Package</span>
             </a>
       </li>
       <li class="   SunItem-7">
            <a href="#" title="Features">
                 <span>Features</span>
           </a> 
       </li>
       <li class="   last-item SunItem-8">
            <a href="#" title="Portfolio">
                <span>Portfolio</span>
            </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </li>
```

You will see I am trying to add more HTML ONLY, this will create a new menu to the right of the mega menu.

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us your code, please.

Comment: These are not elements, they're a pair of closing tags followed by a pair of opening tags. jQuery only allows inserting complete elements, unless you accumulate markup in a string and use `html()`. You may have to change your design.

Comment: can you share some more context to the html structure

Comment: looks like it still creates a invalid html structure..

Comment: Edits added, it will create what is a valid HTML structure

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking in markup, but by the time you're interacting with the structure, it's not markup anymore, it's a DOM structure.

It looks like what you want to do is start a new `ul` after the existing `ul` and move that `li` into it. If so:

```
var lastItem = $("li.last-item");
var currentList = lastItem.closest('ul');
var newList = $("<ul>");
newList.insertAfter(currentList);
newList.append(lastItem);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/anoVaPA/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/anoVaPA/1/edit)